# Splash screen implementation in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter and I wanted to have splash screen in my app. I used initState() and the navigator. But it didn't work. The app opens the splashscreen appears but after that it does not navigate to the next screen.

My main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bmi/HomePage.dart';
import 'dart:async';

main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
 }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SplashScreen();
 }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SplashScreenState();
  }
}

class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>{
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(
        seconds: 4
      ),
      (){
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(),
          )
        );
      }
  );
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: Text(
        'Welcome to BMI Calculator',
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15.0,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

And my HomePage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
             title: Text(
              'BMI Calculator',
               style: new TextStyle(
                 color: Colors.white
               ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

How can I resolve this?

Since I am new to flutter I dont know whether this is the right way to implement splashScreen if there are any other easier ways can you please suggest that also.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Code Corrected:

> MaterialApp should be the parent(root) of all Widgets.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bmi/HomePage.dart';
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: SplashScreen()); // define it once at root level.
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SplashScreenState();
  }
}

class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(),
          ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: Text(
        'Welcome to BMI Calculator',
        style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: Text(
            'BMI Calculator',
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: you can use `pushReplacement`, replace `push` with it @DarlanDieterich

Comment: Note: this splash appears after initial load. Meaning, you might still see a white screen when launching the app. See [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen) regarding implementing splash screen

Answer (score 10):

The splash screen implementation is provided by default.
You just need to change the code in respective platforms like below
For Android: 
Go to android directory in your flutter project and find the res folder where you will have launch_background.xml under drawables , just replace your own splash image as below.
 `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
     <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
         <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
        <item>
         <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/hotel_logo_new" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

For iOS 
- just change the LaunchImage under ImageAssets.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `pushReplacement` instead of `push` when you exit the splash screen to prevent it from showing again when you press the back button.

here's the anmol.majhail code with the correct behavior.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bmi/HomePage.dart';
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: SplashScreen()); // define it once at root level.
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SplashScreenState();
  }
}

class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(),
          ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: Text(
        'Welcome to BMI Calculator',
        style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: Text(
            'BMI Calculator',
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use this package : add the dependency to your pubspec.yaml file.

```
dependencies:
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    splashscreen:
```

How to use

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplashScreen(
        seconds: 10,
        imageBackground: AssetImage('assets/images/a.jpg'),
        navigateAfterSeconds: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    ); // define it once at root level.
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text(
          'Home',
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you so much, easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution which i use in every app.

Use `Timer` class in build method code snippet

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Splash createState() => Splash();
}

class Splash extends State<SplashScreen>  {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Timer(
            Duration(seconds: 3),
                () =>
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => LandingScreen())));


    var assetsImage = new AssetImage(
        'images/new_logo.png'); //<- Creates an object that fetches an image.
    var image = new Image(
        image: assetsImage,
        height:300); //<- Creates a widget that displays an image.

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        /* appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("MyApp"),
          backgroundColor:
              Colors.blue, //<- background color to combine with the picture :-)
        ),*/
        body: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child: new Center(
            child: image,
          ),
        ), //<- place where the image appears
      ),
    );
  }
}
```