# Not able to change the size of the default splash screen icon in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen, launcher

I am using the default splash screen provided by flutter. The app icon shows in the middle of the screen. But it appears very small. If I go to the `launch_background.xml` , I am not able to change the size properties of the bitmap. How to change the size of the bitmap ?

The `launch_background.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
     <item>
         <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/dev_icon" />

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784620/flutter-how-to-change-the-size-of-image-in-splash-screen), but of no use.

Any help is appreciated. I am a complete beginner in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your main function, use home as SplashScreen(_), the parameters are as follows and change the logo size.

```
runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: CustomSplash(
    imagePath: '@drawable/dev_icon',
    backGroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
    animationEffect: 'zoom-in',
    logoSize: 200,
    home: MyApp(),
    customFunction: duringSplash,
    duration: 2500,
    type: CustomSplashType.StaticDuration,
    outputAndHome: op,
),
```